# a SQL query for sum of all the values of a column

Tags: sql-server

i want a sql query the result like the below :

LineNumber          UnitPrice      Quantity

---

```
  1                14               12      
  2                09               10      
  3                34                5       
  4                18                9      
  5                42               40       
  6                07               10      
  7                45               15    
                                   -----   
                                   101
```

pls help me....

Answer (score 3):

To get the total you will use an aggregate:

```
select sum(quantity) Total
from yourtable
```

To return the data from your table:

```
select LineNumber, UnitPrice, Quantity
from yourTable
```

To return them together you can use a `UNION ALL`:

```
select LineNumber, UnitPrice, Quantity
from yourTable
UNION ALL
select 0, 0, sum(quantity) Total
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bf938/3)

Answer (score 3):

Another way

```
WITH YourTable(LineNumber, UnitPrice, Quantity)
     AS (SELECT 1, 14,12
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, 09, 10
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3, 34, 5
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 4, 18, 9
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 5, 42, 40
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 6, 07, 10
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 7, 45, 15)
SELECT LineNumber,
       UnitPrice,
       SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity
FROM   YourTable
GROUP  BY GROUPING SETS ( ( LineNumber, UnitPrice, Quantity ), ( ) )
```

Comment: `GROUPING SETS` is definitely the easiest, I was in the middle of adding it to my solution when you posted this.

Comment: @sravanracha - That is just for demo purposes! You just need the bit starting `SELECT LineNumber ...` (and do I need to point out to change the `YourTable` as required?)

Comment: @JackDouglas WITH ROLLUP produces slightly different results - a summary row for every tier, rather than just the single summary row you can define with GROUPING SETS. This is definitely preferable to ROLLUP. The syntax is more convoluted in the cases where you do really want rollups at each tier, but that's probably not common.

Comment: @Aaron did you check my SQLFiddle? You can use brackets in the same way as GROUPING SETS

Comment: @Jack no, sorry, I did not. I assumed your link went to the MSDN documentation. In any case, I'm not sure what advantage ROLLUP has - along with COMPUTE etc. it is likely on the deprecation path.

Comment: @Aaron Are you thinking of the non-standard variant? The one I used is unlikely to go away and along with CUBE is a helpful shorthand where the full-blown GROUPING SETS is unnecessary.

Comment: No, I am just predicting that ROLLUP will follow the same path as COMPUTE eventually.

Answer (score 1):

```
-- For all the data from the table
SELECT [LineNumber], [UnitPrice], [Quantity] FROM [SomeTable]

-- For the sum of the quantity field.
SELECT SUM([Quantity]) AS [Sum] FROM [SomeTable]
```